# Swift doesn't return the localized version for URLResourceKey.localizedNameKey

Tags: swift

I'm in Italy and the following code should return the localized name for the Preview.app but it returns `Preview.app`

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/Applications/Preview.app")
let v = try! url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.localizedNameKey])
print(v.localizedName!)
```

I've checked the returned language and it is correct

```
let language = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
print(language)
```

The Objective-C version works fine and returns `Anteprima` the italian localization for `/Applications/Preview.app`

```
NSString* displayName = nil;
NSURL* u = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Applications/Preview.app"];
[u getResourceValue:&displayName forKey:NSURLLocalizedNameKey error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", displayName);
```

Where is the error?

Comment: Just to thicken the plot, try it with just `"/Applications/"`. I get the proper `Applicazioni`.

Comment: If I start a bare Mac OS X project in Xcode 8 / Swift 3, and set the "Localization native development region" to "it", it works. If I use instead: `UserDefaults.standard.set(["it"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")` it does not work even though `NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]` returns `it`. So `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` does something more than AppleBundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fine.

I'll bet you have a separate Swift project, and just forgot to set `CFBundleLocalizations` in `Info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
  <string>en</string>
  <string>it</string>
</array>
```

Anything not in this array won't work properly.

Comment: Thanks this works!! I don't understand why the Objective-C project doesn't require this setting to work but it's ok for me :)